How to Retrieve Token Metadata Including Social Networks in URI Using Python
I'm working on a project where I need to extract metadata from a token, specifically the social networks listed in its URI. I've attempted to use the getAccountInfo method via websockets, but it didn't yield the expected results.
Could someone suggest alternative methods or libraries in Python that could help me retrieve this information? Any examples or guidance on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

I managed to solve my own question. After exploring various options, I found that the DexScanner API provides a straightforward way to retrieve the general information of a token, including the metadata I was interested in.
It appears that Metaplex might be an option, but it seems to primarily support JavaScript. I'm continuing my search for additional solutions that can be implemented with Python. If anyone knows of other APIs or methods, feel free to share.
I hope this helps anyone facing a similar challenge!
